# PHP - set array into object

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, codeigniter

I really don't know how to transform array in object.

what I need is my array could transform into like this object :

```
    var locations= [
        {lat: -22.9, lng: -43.23},
        {lat: 23.03, lng: 113.12},
        {lat: 23.12, lng: 113.25},
        {lat: -7.24917, lng: 112.75083},
        {lat: -6.323116, lng: 106.870941},
        {lat: 40.69, lng: -73.99},
        {lat: 40.74, lng: -73.94}
    ];
```

I retrieve the data with ajax :

```
$(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url         : '<?= base_url('admin/getCustomerLatLong'); ?>',
            method      : 'GET',
            // dataType : 'JSON',
            success     : function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Error while getting the data. Call the developer!');
            }
        });
    });
```

and I am using codeigniter, here is `getCustomerLatLong` function in my controller:

```
public function getCustomerLatLong() {
    $data = $this->M_customer->getAllCustomers()->result();
    $locations = array();

    foreach ($data as $location) :
        $locations['lat'] = $location->latKota;
        $locations['lng'] = $location->lngKota;
        echo json_encode($locations);
    endforeach;
}
```

please any answer would be helpful for me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would imagine you issue is down to the fact that you're using `echo` inside your loop.

Try changing your controller to something like:

```
public function getCustomerLatLong()
{
    $data = $this->M_customer->getAllCustomers()->result();
    $locations = [];

    foreach ($data as $location) {

        $locations[] = [
            'lat' => $location->latKota,
            'lng' => $location->lngKota,
        ];
    }

    echo json_encode($locations);

}
```

You might also need to uncomment `dataType : 'JSON',`

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks man, by the way have you ever used google maps marker cluster?  I got the problem in set all the markers based on those locations. I have try in many ways but still the markers didn't show up, and my console log didn't show any errors too.

Comment: I've haven't used them in a long time, however, if you open up another question I'm sure someone should be able to help :)